# Math indentation environment

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment

I'd often like to set formulas like

[image]

Is there some other way than doing this by manually inserting whitespace (with `\quad` etc.), i.e., something like

```
\begin{align*}
f( & 1 + g( & 2 + \\
   &        & 3), \\
   & 4 + 5 + 6 + 7)
\end{align*}
```

So in the first line which contains an `n`th `&` symbol, its horizontal position should be remembered. When a subsequent line contains an `n`th `&` symbol, the text should continue at the remembered position.

Afaik `align` etc. can't do this because `2 +` and `3` would be moved to the right because `4 + 5 + 6 + 7)` occupies too much space.

Comment: I'm curious, can you say _why_ you'd like to do that?

Comment: I occasionally have long (~3 lines) logical formulas with large terms. One example contains an if-then-else with conjunctions with a \max with a \sum with a large term. Thank you so much for all the answers!

Comment: @HendrikVogt I know it's been a year since you've asked this question but let me still add this: the example might be too minimalistic to see the benefit but it's actually just the indentation scheme most used for programming languages so it makes sense to me to structure equations the same way. Too bad LaTeX has such a poor support for this as of know :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Use an `array` for stacking, and drop the intercolumn space, as needed using `@{}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{array}{r@{}l@{}l}
    f( & 1 + g( & 2 + \\
       &        & 3), \\
       & \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{4 + 5 + 6 + 7)}
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

If you wish for a more breathable presentation, use `\\[\jot]` instead of just `\\`.

Comment: You should mention that this switches all content to inline mode so anything a bit more complex than the MWE suddenly becomes tiny.

Comment: @Christian: Yes, elements within the `array` environment default to `\textstyle` (which is similar to what you get when using inline math mode `$..$`). You can switch back by inserting `\displaystyle` wherever needed.

Answer (score 7):

You can also do this with either:

1. the `alignat` environment along with `\matrlap{}`, or
2. with the `align` and use a `\hphantom{}` to obtain:

[image]

---

### 1. Using `\alignat` and `\mathrlap`:

The `alignat` provides multiple `rl` align pairs.  Since your second alignment is intended to be `l` aligned, you use a double `&&`.  The first `&` skips over the `r` aligned column of the `rl` align pair.

`\mathrlap` and related macros are discussed in detail in [this TuGboat paper](http://math.arizona.edu/%7Eaprl/publications/mathclap/perlis_mathclap_24Jun2003.pdf).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{3}
    f( & 1 + g( && 2 + \\
       &        && 3), \\
       & \mathrlap{4 + 5 + 6 + 7)}
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

---

### 2. Using `\align` and `\hphantom`:

You could also just use a `\hphantom{}` to insert the exact horizontal spacing as is required by its parameter.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    f( & 1 + g( 2 + \\
       & \hphantom{1 + g(} 3), \\
       & 4 + 5 + 6 + 7)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{array}{ r @{} l @{\mkern\thinmuskip} r }
    f( & 1 + g( & 2 + \\
       &        & 3), \\
       & \mathrlap{4 + 5 + 6 + 7)}
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an excellent question. I face the same problem when typesetting page-long formulas. In the absence of a math display environment with tabbing capabilities, I typeset stuff such as this:

```
\documentclass{article}\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{mathtools}\mathtoolsset{mathic=true}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabbing}
\(f(\)\=\(1 + g(\)\=\kill
\(f(\)\>\(1 + g(\)\>\(2 \,+\)\\[\jot]
\>\>\(3),\)\\[\jot]
\>\(4 + 5 + 6 + 7)\)
\end{tabbing}
%%% Won't work:
% \[
% \begin{tabbing}
% f( \= 1 + g( \=\kill
% f( \> 1 + g( \> 2 \,+\\[\jot]
% \>\> 3),\\[\jot]
% \>4 + 5 + 6 + 7)
% \end{tabbing}
% \]
%%% Badly needed:
% \begin{mathtabbing}
% f( \= 1 + g( \=\kill
% f( \> 1 + g( \> 2 \,+\\
% \>\> 3),\\
% \>4 + 5 + 6 + 7)
% \end{mathtabbing}
%%% How much effort is it to produce such a mathtabbing environment?
\end{document}
```

Result after running `latex` and converting DVI into a PNG:
[image: result after latex + convert]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please explain your used code?

Comment: @Mensch Yes, but not everything. Let us concentrate on the stuff you don't understand. What is the first command in my code that you don't understand?

Comment: You missunderstood me: it is usual here to explain the used code instead of only showing some code. Suppose, there are users not knowing your used commands, they have at the moment no change to understand what is going on ...

Comment: @Mensch No, you are wrong. Folks do have a freedom to leave their code unexplained. As an example, consider the answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/521068 without any explanations whatsoever. Complain there first.