# Tabbing for math mode?

Tags: math-mode, align, tabbing

I'm looking for something synonymous to `tabbing`, but for math mode.

I read that `alignat*` should do the trick, but this behaves differently it seems. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
S_4^{t} &= \{&\langle rdi, r12, rax' \rangle \mid \langle rdi, r12, rax \rangle \in S_4~\wedge \\
&& rax' = \{ rax \mid rax > 0 \} \}\\
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

The second line appears to be right aligned, whereas I would like the `&` markers to be aligned with each other and then all text left aligned (like in `tabbing`).

Is anyone able to fix this code, or suggest an alternative.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx), and thanks for posting a complete [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Answer (score 7):

As per [Math indentation environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60272/math-indentation-environment), the `alignat` provides multiple `rl` align pairs. Since your second alignment is intended to be `l` aligned, you need to use a double &&. The first & skips over the `r` aligned column of the `rl` align pair:

[image]

### Notes:

- The `align` environment also provides multiple `rl` alignment pairs.
  However, the `alignat` does *not* insert additional space that the `align` environment does between the `rl` alignment pairs.
  So, for cases where a separation is required between the alignment points with the `alignat` environment those would need to be inserted manually.
- An alternative is to use the `array` environment. But one does need to be careful to remove inter column spacing using `@{}`, and to ensure that the relational or binary operators have the correct spacing by using `{}` to make TeX think that there is an element on the other side of the operator.  This produces results identical to the above.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
S_4^{t} &= \{&&\langle rdi, r12, rax' \rangle \mid \langle rdi, r12, rax \rangle \in S_4~\wedge \\
        &    &&rax' = \{ rax \mid rax > 0 \} \}
\end{alignat*}

\[\begin{array}{l@{}l@{}l}
S_4^{t} &{}= \{&\langle rdi, r12, rax' \rangle \mid \langle rdi, r12, rax \rangle \in S_4~\wedge \\
        &      &rax' = \{ rax \mid rax > 0 \} \} \\
\end{array}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there an environment that aligns all cells left? There must be.

Comment: @vext01: You could use the `array` environment, but have to be careful about math spacing issues. I'll add an example.