# How much work is it to implement tabbing in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, tabbing

Resuming http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60272, how difficult is it to implement tabbing in math mode (inline or display)?  E.g., we would sometimes like to type

```
\documentclass{article}\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{mathtools}\mathtoolsset{mathic=true}
\begin{document}
\begin{mathtabbing}
f( \= 1 + g( \=\kill
f( \> 1 + g( \> 2 \,+\\
\>\> 3),\\
\>4 + 5 + 6 + 7)
\end{mathtabbing}
\end{document}
```

and obtain

[image: output]

(presumably, upon adding a mathtabbing environment in the preamble).

Yes, of course we'd like to have some more special commands, at the very least `\=`, `\>`, `\'`, and \` . Cf. http://www.emerson.emory.edu/services/latex/latex2e/latex2e_61.html .

The problem with the solutions described in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60272 is that for many-line formulas, they all need significant typesetting effort, either in terms of a bunch of `\hphantom`s, a bunch of `\mathrlap`s, or `tabbing` with tons of math mode escapes. Having `\>` would be way more comfortable.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{mathtools}\mathtoolsset{mathic=true}
\begin{document}

{\makeatletter
\def\color@setgroup{\begingroup\set@color}
\def\color@begingroup{\begingroup$\displaystyle}
\def\color@endgroup{\ifmmode$\fi\endgraf\endgroup}
\def\color@hbox{\hbox\bgroup\color@begingroup}
\def\color@vbox{\vbox\bgroup\color@begingroup}
\def\color@endbox{\color@endgroup\egroup}

\begin{tabbing}
f( \= 1 + g( \=\kill
f( \> 1 + g( \> 2 \,+\\
\>\> 3),\\
\>4 + 5 + 6 + 7)
\end{tabbing}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What unit are you using to measure work? Newtons?

Comment: @JonathanKomar far too modern:  lbf